# Render single react component instead of complete application from server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side, server-side-rendering, serverside-javascript

I went through many articles on server side rendering of react and the all of them has the following in common :-

- The server route renders a complete html page with a div which wraps the root react component, just like traditional react code
- it also includes reference to a bundle.js which is called by browser once the skeleton is loaded and the view re-renders with all javascript functionality.

This approach always leads me to download my whole frontend app in one go.
Is there any way where I can selectively render react components in divs? .
What I mean to say is, for example "/graph" only gives me graph component, "/table" only gives me table component etc so that :-

- I can embed react components into a pre-existing webapp.
- The response from the routes are just smaller components instead of the whole outer root component. I know react can be embedded in other web apps in case of client side rendering, but I am wondering if same thing can be achieved in server side rendering.
  Thanks.

Comment: *download my whole frontend app in one go* - what do you mean? You don't need to download anything on server side.

Comment: @estus the bundle.js is basically packing the whole frontend code , which browser makes a request for.

Comment: What is the app? Do you have client-side routing? React Router?

Comment: No, I just want to load render individual componenets from server.

Comment: You have XY problem. React is isomorphic. This means that it can run on both client and server side if you did everything properly. That you don't have React routing means that you need to write same code twice on both sides to render route-specific components. Usually there is no need to do that. You could avoid that by using React router that does that universally.